# Multiple regression beta is just $X^{-1}y$?? why not?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

In multiple linear regression, the formula is
$$\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$

but we all know that
$$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
thank we can say that
$$(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$
$$=X^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}X^Ty$$
$$=X^{-1}y$$

then

$$\hat\beta=X^{-1}y$$

right?
But why don't they say like this??

-===========

In multiple linear regression,
they say we can find error of $\hat\beta$ like this.
$$b-\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty-\beta$$
$$= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+\epsilon)-\beta$$
$$= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon   $$

And I can't understand how to jump from second line to third.
If I assume that $(X^TX)^{-1}=X^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}$, it makes sense. But you can't tell if $x$ is invertible or a square.
How can I get this?

Comment: Why would X be invertible? Why would it even be square?

Comment: @MatthewTowers Oh that's right..Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewTowers then how do you think about the next problem I wrote below?

Comment: you're assuming that $X^TX$ is invertible for any of this to make sense. If so then for sure $(X^TX)^{-1} (X^TX) = I$, getting you from line 2 to line 3.

Comment: @MatthewTowers  Thank you!!